# Send Div id to javascript via onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a page with several div's.  All of the divs have a unique id.  I would like to send that id to a javascript function.  I have tried to save it as a value as well, and send this.value, but that does not work either.

```
<div class='recordElem$val' id='$rname' value='$rname'
onclick='javascript:updateRecord(this.value);'>
        $name</div>"
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is a jQuery answer

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   function clicked(item) {
    alert($(item).attr("id"));
   }
  </script>


  <div onclick="clicked(this);" id="test">test</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do that through href?

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at two ways to solve this problem

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="scopeId" onclick="javascript:testScope.call(this)">Using scope</div>
    <div id="parameterId" onclick="javascript:testId(this.id)">Using Parameter</div>
    <script>
        function testScope(){
            alert("Scope: " + this.id)
        }
        function testId(id){
            alert("Parameter: " + id)
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `onclick="updateRecord(this)"` and handle it like this:

```
function updateRecord(div) {
  // statements
  var id = div.id; // or however you want to use the id
  // statements
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign php variables value to javascript variable value. Then you can use it onclick
example:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var a=<?php echo $tabs['menu_id']; ?>

    </script>

    <a href="index.php" onclick="show_center(a);">pass it</a>
```

Here we can pass javascript's variable to function.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing this.id to the javascript function?

Comment: I tried this originally, and for some reason it did not work.  Now it works perfectly.